# Database removal of old entries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

My question is more of a high level question than technology specific.

The problem I have is I am inserting into a database a list of users corresponding to a machine.  When I do so I have no idea what users were previously but I want to remove users who are in the database that correspond to that machine but no longer are current.

The list that I have is the current list of users for that machine.  Any ideas?

Solution 1:

1. Query DB to get a list of users corresponding to a machine.
2. Compare against current list and build a remove list and an add list.
3. Execute Remove
4. Execute Add

Drawbacks to this solution is that we execute 3 store procedure statements.
Positive is we don't have to change the database.

Solution 2:

1. Add a user timestamp field to the table.
2. Run add all users while updating the timestamp field.
3. Execute new stored procedure to remove all users corresponding 
   to machine whose updated is less than now.

Drawback is we add a field to each row.
Positive is this is likely only 2 queries.

Comment: You mean, to check existence of the user before insert?

Comment: This depends on the technology. In sql server I would suggest using MERGE. I am not very familiar with other DBMS but I am sure most of them have something similar.

Comment: [I actually wouldn't suggest `MERGE`. Especially as a starting point](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Comment: For MySQL, you can opt for `on duplicate key update` I believe. Which DBMS you are asking for?

Comment: Bertrand, +1 for the link, I wasn't aware of any of that.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: No I don't mean to check existence before insert.  It is more check to make sure old data is removed.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest solution from my perspective is to alter the table so that you add a datetime or timestamp that defaults to the current time, and on update updates to the current time.  That way, when the table is altered this update occurs.  Then build a job to run every X period (daily, weekly, monthly, etc) that removes users who have not been updated in some period.

This gives you the most control over your database, and the most accurate data after a short period.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. Why not:

```
-- Add any new machines
INSERT [Table] (MACHINE, [USER]) 
SELECT MACHINE, [USER] FROM Query Q WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Table] T WHERE T.MACHINE = Q.MACHINE)

-- Delete any removed machines
DELETE [Table] WHERE Machine NOT IN (SELECT Machine FROM Query)

-- Update any changed machines
UPDATE
  A
SET
  A.CoName = B.CoName
  --SELECT *
FROM
  Cust A 
  JOIN (SELECT CustID, CoName FROM Cust) B 
    ON A.CustID = B.CustID AND A.CoName <> B.CoName
```

Updated my answer to cover new machines and removed machines. Wrap it all up in a Stored Procedure.

Comment: I wish I knew more SQL so I understood what this is doing although I would assume it would be doing the very thing solution 1 is doing but in SQL.

Comment: What is Query?  I presume that would be the list of current users?   The current user list is not coming from the database but rather from a client reporting up.  Can I pass this list to SQL in a way I can use it like you use Query?

Comment: Because I don't know your table names the above solution is in pseudo code. Query is simply a placeholder for the way you actually  get your information on machines and users. The above code simply keeps "Table" up to date with the latest state of "Query". As I suggested, it would be best to put the above statements into a stored procedure and run it whenever necessary.